# wordpress get result give some value null

Tags: wordpress

```
$posts = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results("SELECT ID,post_content, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type='post'  LIMIT 1");

$permalink=get_permalink($posts[ID]);
$title=$posts[post_title];
$content=$posts[post_content];

$file = fopen("D://sam7.txt", "w");
fwrite($file,$permalink);
fclose($file);

$file = fopen("D://sam8.txt", "w");
fwrite($file,$title);
fclose($file);
```

Im unable to print $title in sam8.txt, but $permalink print properly. 
how can i get the value of title.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your syntax. Please check the syntax below:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID,post_content,post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type='post'  LIMIT 1;"));

$permalink = get_permalink( $results[0]->ID );
$title = $results[0]->post_title;
$content = $results[0]->post_content;
```

The rest of your code looks fine. Do let me know if this is working for you or not.